# Find the least multiplier of a fraction that gives a remainder of 1

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have two natural numbers $2\le b\lt a$. I want to know the least natural number $x_1$ such that $\frac{xa}{b}$ gives a remainder of $1$, and the least natural number $x_2$ such that the remainder is $b-1$ (I'm looking for a formula, not an algorithmic procedure).

In other words, that

$$
\frac{x_1a}{b}-\left\lfloor\frac{x_1a}{b}\right\rfloor=\frac{1}{b}\\
\frac{x_2a}{b}-\left\lfloor\frac{x_2a}{b}\right\rfloor=\frac{b-1}{b}\\
$$

Assume that $a$ is not divisible by $b$, so that both $x$ exist.

Under that assumption, I know that $x_1,x_2\in [1, \ldots, b - 1]$ because all possible remainders from $0$ up to $b-1$ happens exactly once when the multipliers goes from $1$ to $b$.

For example, for $\frac{19}{7}$ iterating a multiplier $x$ over $1, 2, \ldots, 7$ gives the following list of remainders:

$$
5 \quad 3\quad 1\quad 6\quad 4\quad2\quad 0
$$

where the position ocuppied by the remainder $1$ ($x_1=3$ in this case), is the "step size" of the remainder list, because it is the number of forward positions, moving in a circular fashion, to reach the next remainder ($2$ appears three positions later, 3, other three positions later, 4, other three positions later, and so on).

About $x_2$, I know that $x_2=mod(x_1(b-1), b)$, but that's not a very useful expression that I could use comfortably in other equations that I'm working on, so I wonder if there's a way to express $x_2$ that doesn't involve the explicit use of modular arithmetic.

Comment: Seems you're looking for a _multiplicative inverse_ of $a$ modulo $b$ (as $x_1$). Is there any particular reason you aren't comfortable with modular arithmetics?

Comment: "I'm looking for a formula, not an algorithmic procedure"  Why should there be one.

Comment: " but that's not a very useful expression that I could use comfortably in other equations that I'm working on"  Why not?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Because I'm not proficient with it, and I'm working with some inequations involving a set of floor functions and fractional parts trying to find/proof properties of a specific problem of mine. Modular arithmetic will just make the problem a bit more harder for me, so I'm trying to avoid it if I can.

Comment: @fleablood Why should I know? That's why I ask :)

Comment: modular arithmetic makes *everything* easier and avoiding modular arithmetic makes everything harder.  And you can learn everything you need to know about modular arithmetic in two sentences: If you divide an integer by an integer $n$ there will be a remainder.  You can do all arithmetic by only paying attention to the remainders and ignoring everything else.  Now you know *everything* you need to know and *everything* will be easier.  (I serious. It will.)